# Cómo conseguir que mi programa en C++ detecte las Ñ

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

Estoy haciendo un programa de OCR, y estoy aún en las primeras fases del proyecto consistente en el "Entrenamiento". El objetivo por tanto de mi programa actual es clasificar objetos en una imagen y procesarlos como caracteres, lo cual consigo con todos los caracteres excepto la Ñ (debido a que está formada por dos objetos y no me los detecta juntos)

Voy a utilizar un algoritmo knn para clasificar mis caracteres, pero antes de eso necesito que mi programa detecte la Ñ como un solo objeto y me permita así guardar la información en un archivo de clasificación.

¿Saben de qué manera puedo lograrlo?

Aquí les dejo el programa:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\ml\ml.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//VARIABLES GLOBALES

const int MIN_CONTORNO_AREA = 100;

const int ANCHO_IMAGEN_REDIM = 20;
const int ALTURA_IMAGEN_REDIM = 30;

//PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL

int main()  {
    cv::Mat imEntrenamiento;
    cv::Mat imGris;
    cv::Mat imGaus;
    cv::Mat imByN;
    cv::Mat imByNcopia;

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > ptContornos;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> v4iJerarquia;

cv::Mat matEnterosParaClasificacion;

cv::Mat matEntrenamientoImComoFlattenedFloats;

std::vector<int> intCaracteresValidos = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
    'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

imEntrenamiento = cv::imread("caracteres_prueba.png");

if (imEntrenamiento.empty())    {
    std::cout << "Error: imagen no leida desde el archivo\n\n";
    return(0);
}

cv::cvtColor(imEntrenamiento, imGris, CV_BGR2GRAY);

cv::GaussianBlur(imGris, imGaus, cv::Size(5, 5), 0);

cv::adaptiveThreshold(imGaus, imByN, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2);

cv::imshow("imByN", imByN);

imByNcopia = imByN.clone();

cv::findContours(imByN, ptContornos, v4iJerarquia, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for (int i = 0; i < ptContornos.size(); i++)    {
    if (cv::contourArea(ptContornos[i]) > MIN_CONTORNO_AREA)    {

        cv::Rect rectanguloDelimitador = cv::boundingRect(ptContornos[i]);

        cv::rectangle(imEntrenamiento, rectanguloDelimitador, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);

        cv::Mat matROI = imByN(rectanguloDelimitador);

        cv::Mat matROIRedimensionada;
        cv::resize(matROI, matROIRedimensionada, cv::Size(ANCHO_IMAGEN_REDIM, ALTURA_IMAGEN_REDIM));

        cv::imshow("matROI", matROI);
        cv::imshow("matROIRedimensionada", matROIRedimensionada);
        cv::imshow("imEntrenamiento", imEntrenamiento);

        int intChar = cv::waitKey(0);

        if (intChar == 27)  {
            return(0);
        }
        else if (std::find(intCaracteresValidos.begin(), intCaracteresValidos.end(), intChar) != intCaracteresValidos.end())    {
            matEnterosParaClasificacion.push_back(intChar);

            cv::Mat matImagenFloat;
            matROIRedimensionada.convertTo(matImagenFloat, CV_32FC1);

            cv::Mat matImagenFlattenedFloat = matImagenFloat.reshape(1, 1);

            matEntrenamientoImComoFlattenedFloats.push_back(matImagenFlattenedFloat);
        }
    }
}
std::cout << "Entrenamiento Completo\n\n";

//GUARDAR LAS CLASIFICACIONES EN UN ARCHIVO

cv::FileStorage fsClasificaciones("clasificaciones.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);

if (fsClasificaciones.isOpened() == false)  {
    std::cout << "Error, no es posible abrir el archivo de clasificacion de entrenamiento, salida del programa\n\n";
    return(0);
}

fsClasificaciones << "clasificaciones" << matEnterosParaClasificacion;
fsClasificaciones.release();

//GUARDAR LAS IMAGENES DE ENTRENAMIENTO EN UN ARCHIVO

cv::FileStorage fsImagenesEntrenamiento("imagenes.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);

if (fsImagenesEntrenamiento.isOpened() == false)    {
    std::cout << "Error, no es posible abrir el archivo de entrenamiento de imagenes, salida del programa\n\n";
    return(0);
}

fsImagenesEntrenamiento << "imagenes" << matEntrenamientoImComoFlattenedFloats;
fsImagenesEntrenamiento.release();

return(0);
```

}

Comment: No sé nada de lenguajes compilados pero: no sería útil extraer el keycode de la ñ y relacionarlo con la búsqueda?

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene tiempo, pero, ¿Por qué no manejar la `Ñ` como dos símbolos? esa característica haría la separación de clases bastante clara a la hora de clasificar mediante el `Knn`. Si necesitas unir ambos símbolos, tal vez una operación morfológica como `closing `con un gran elemento estructurante, pero esto seguro distorsiona el resto de los blobs. Tal vez detectar el número de componentes para cada letra, luego guardar esta característica, y en caso de que se detecten dos símbolos, tratar de ubicar y posteriormente eliminar la tilde, y procesar el blob como el resto de las letras.

Answer (score 0):

intenta incluir  `#include <clocale>` y luego utilizala de esta manera en el main `setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Spanish");` Saludos.

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene nada que ver con el problema. El problema es de visión computacional, y se debe resolver utilizando algúna técnica de procesamiento de imágenes.